# How do I call app.use() inside another app.use()

Tags: express

I have a simple server like:

/**** server******/

```
const express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    parser = require('xml2json'), 
    app = express();

app.set('trig', {'name':false, 'date':false});
app.set('port', 3000);  

app.use('/api/login', require('./routes/_login.js'));
app.use('/api/tasks', require('./routes/_tasks.js'));

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {    
res.sendfile("index.html");
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {});
// end
```

to run: 
app.use('/api/tasks', require('./routes/_tasks.js')); I have to have the trig to be set - as default it's elementa are false
To do so I need to run:
app.use('/api/login', require('./routes/_login.js'));

How may I run the login route inside tasks?

/******** _login.js ********/

```
var express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    parser = require('xml2json'),
    router = express.Router();

var url = 'http://url';

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var app = req.app;

    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress || (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null);
    var xml = `<xml><User="*****" Password="*****"/></xml>`;
    var options = {
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
            "x-forwarded-for": ip,
            "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(xml)
        }, body: xml
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var json = parser.toJson(body);
            json = JSON.parse(json);
            var name= json.xml.res['trig'];
            var date = new Date();
            app.set('trig',{'name':name, 'date':date.setDate(date.getDate())});
            res.end();
      }else{
          res.send(error);
      }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

/******* _tasks.js *********/

I need to pass task.name into xml that needs to be sent

I do:

1. var app = req.app;
2. var tasks = app.get('tasks');

now I can read it and all I need to do is check if it's not false

```
var app = req.app;
var tasks = app.get('tasks');

if(!tasks.name){
    app.use('/api/login', require('./_login.js'));
}
```

this does not work

```
var express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    parser = require('xml2json'),
    router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var app = req.app;
    var tasks = app.get('tasks');

    if(!tasks.name){
        app.use('/api/login', require('./_login.js'));
    } 

    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress || (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null);
    var url = 'http://url';
    var xml = `<xml type="tasks" trig="${task.name}"/>`;
    var options = { 
        url: url,
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
            "x-forwarded-for": ip,
            "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(xml)
        }, body: xml
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var json = parser.toJson(body);
            json = JSON.parse(json);
            res.jsonp(json);
            res.end();
      }else{
          res.send(error);
      }
    }); 

});

module.exports = router;
```

please give me a tip how to make it right
Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: without task.name I will not be able to send the other requests

Comment: @jonrsharpe  what is the proper way to do it?